# Display fields depending on selected with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add fields depending on what the user selects in the drop down list. For example if a user picks 1 from the list nothing happens, if they pick 2 a text field appears, if they pick 3 two text boxes appear and so on. So far I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field1, #field1, #field3').hide();

    $('#tickets1').change(function () {
        $(this).toggle(this.value == '2') 
        $('#field1').show();
    });
});

<!--the select just comes from xml/example in html is fine-->
<select name="tickets1" id="tickets1" title="{outbound_inbound/number_of_tickets/@title}">
    <xsl:for-each select="outbound_inbound/tickets/number">     
        <option value="{self::node()}"><xsl:value-of select="self::node()" /></option>
    </xsl:for-each>
</select>

<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" title="" /><br />
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" title="" /><br />
<input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" title="" /><br />
```

so, if they pick 2 tickets field1 appears, 3 tickets fields1 and 2 appear and 4 tickets fields 1,2 and 3 appear.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"if they pick 2 tickets field1 appears, 3 tickets fields1 and 2 appear and 3 tickets fields 1,2 and 3 appear."_ Doesn't make sense. You have the three tickets condition twice. That, and shouldn't `$('#tickets2').change(function () {` be `$('#tickets1').change(function () {`?

Comment: None of the selectors match, the first one have `field1` twice, the second one has `tickets2`, but the select ID is `tickets1`, and `$(this).toggle()` means toggle the select element, but why would you toggle that ? To many inconsistencies!

Comment: Sorry, its been a long day. edited

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select name="tickets1" id="tickets1"">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" value="2" /><br />
<input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" value="3" /><br />
```

JS

```
/* Considering that the select element and text inputs are siblings */
        $('#tickets1').change(function(e) {
            // Get all text input fields
            var $input = $(this).nextAll('input[type="text"]'),
            // Calculate index of the input that match the select value selected
            // -2 because of the 0 based index and constraint "if they pick 2 tickets field1 appears"
                sliceIndex = +this.value -2;
            if(sliceIndex < 0){
                $input.hide();
            } else $input.slice(sliceIndex).add( $input.prevAll('input')).show().end().nextAll('input').hide();
        });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/cbg3z/)

Comment: @Hatzi does this make sense to you ?